# 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token' when i want to show php array element in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, multidimensional-array

My php array variable is `$ques1 = $multiD['ques1']['ques']`. the output in php of this variable is = 'this is the output'.
My javascript code is

```
 <script>
    var js_array = "<?php echo $multiD['ques1']['ques'] ?>" ;
    document.write(js_array);
</script>
```

In the 'console' section it is showing  **Invalid or unexpected token**
And in the 'sources' section it is showing below text

```
   <script>
     var js_element = "<p>This is the output</p>" ;
     document.write(js_element);
  </script>
```

Please Help. What is the problem in this code

Comment: PHP scripts work only in PHP files.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the error with the code provided.  Are you sure the JavaScript error isn't pointing to a different line somewhere else?  Does the error say what the unexpected token is?

Comment: Did you document.open before? What are you trying to accomplish with your script?